# Model transformation to platform specific (NC) code

Tags: java, xsd, transformation, ecore, qvt

Tools experience wear during usage. Machines using these tools need to have their NC (i.e. numerical control) programs corrected, after the wear is measured.

I've already created a XSD model and generated JAXB classes that manage these measures, now I want to automatically generate NC code that sets the measured differences on the machines.

The code to be generated basically has this format (plus possibly some static prefixing/suffixing code):

```
$TC_DP<x>[<t>, <D>] // 1 < x <= 25, 1 < D <= 12
```

with `t`being the ID of the tool, `D` being a cutting edge on this tool, and `x`being a parameter related to the cutting edge.

For different tools `t`, `x` and `D` have different meaning, e.g. `$TC_DP1[10, 2]` is *length* of edge 2 on tool 10. `$TC_DP1[5, 2]` could be *width* of edge 2 on tool 5.

---

I'm looking for a way to declaratively define the mapping between the `$TC_DP<x>[<t>, <D>]` format and the model I've created, in order to have the NC code generated for me.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you provide, just about any declarative transformation tool is the same.

You define computations (typically OCL queries) that relate each of your new values to your old values. These computations are wrapped up in mappings/relations/rules to create the new objects whose slots contain the new values.

If you want to code this declaratively today I would suggest ATL or Henshin. QVTr is still a bit of a future prospect. QVTo can give you a semi-declarative solution.

Comment: My main goal is to minimize the production and maintenance effort. Can you recommend imperative transformations in my case?

Comment: QVTo is imperative. I called it semi-declarative because it can be written fairly declaratively.